# sts4 how can connect Controller with html?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Trying to connect a Controller and html files in sts4.
But instead of index.html connection, just browser showing "index" string on the screen.
How can i connect with a html file and Controller.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please **don't** post your code as an image. See if you wonder why: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, I've done the following:

1. Instead of the annotation `@RestController` on the class, I've applied `@Controller`.
2. *`html`-files* should reside in the following location: `resources/templates/`.